# Need help to use groupBy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the occurrence of first character of string in array elements in python
ex. `sample = ["abc","def","ade", "acf", "bal"]`

Output:

```
a = 3
b = 1
d = 1
```

Comment: why `pandas`? okay `pd.Series(sample).str[0].reset_index().groupby(0).count()`

Comment: Do not just request something, tell what you have already tried and paste the relevant code here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.groupby`, you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby

{k: sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(sample), key=lambda x: x[:1])}
# {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}
```

However, since your data is not sorted, `collections.Counter` is the sounder approach:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(x[:1] for x in sample)
# Counter({'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged pandas but there's a `Collections` alternative also -

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([i[0] for i in sample])
```

O/P -

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged pandas, so create a dataframe from the sample:

```
sample = ["abc","def","ade", "acf", "bal"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['sample'] = sample
```

Then groupby using the first letter of the string and count:

```
df.groupby(df['sample'].str[0]).count()
```

use this dataframe as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
result ={}
sample = ["abc","def","ade", "acf", "bal"]
for first,*rest in sample:
    result[first] = result.get(first,0) + 1
print(result)

{'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'b': 1}
```

You also had a `pandas` tag:

```
pd.Series(sample).str[0].reset_index().groupby(0).count()
   index
0       
a      3
b      1
d      1
```